# How to loop the program's asking for new set of inputs in c++?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a,b;
    cout << "Enter two positive numbers:" <<endl;
    cin >> a >> b;
    if (a<b) cout <<a<<" is less than "<< b<<endl;
    else if (a>b) cout <<a<<" is greater than " <<b<<endl;
    }
```

How can I make the program endlessly repeat asking for a new set of numbers as input?

Comment: Are you wondering how to write a loop in general, or specifically how to write a loop that never terminates?

Comment: What would you do if you wanted your program to print certain line endlessly? Reading from input is no different.

Comment: "How do I have loop in C++" is generally considered a bit too trivial question for SO, as it is answered so early in any C++ tutorial, book or other learning material.

Comment: Read https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_while_loop.asp

Comment: @developer, You can do it by using any loop with a condition for asking for i/p endlessly.

Comment: @molbdnilo I know how to loop, my question is if it is possible to loop without setting any condition on asking for new input.

Comment: @ Narendra Is it possible to do it without setting a condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the simplest way of doing what you want (there are other ways). Basically, you just need to 'wrap' the code that you want to repeat in a loop, where the 'test' condition for the loop will **always** evaluate to **true**.

Note the comments with "///" I've given:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
//using namespace std; /// Search this site for "Why using namespace std is bad"
using std::cout;/// Just declare usage of those feature you ACTUALLY use...
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    int a, b;
    while (true) { /// The test condition will always be "TRUE" so the loop will never end!
        cout << "Enter two positive numbers:" << endl;
        cin >> a >> b;
        if (a < b) cout << a << " is less than " << b << endl;
        else if (a > b) cout << a << " is greater than " << b << endl;
    //  cout /// This line is wrong!
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I needed.

Comment: Thanks too, for the tips! Why is the  cout line wrong?

Comment: @developer First, there is a syntax error because there is no `;` at the end of the statement. But, even if you add this, the statement `cout;` doesn't do anything - it's just like writing a statement like, for example, `a;` (not a compiler error, but entirely without effect). What were you trying to accomplish with this line?

Comment: That's a shame! I have to edit my post. That's an accidental error.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what exactly do you want your program to do. If you want it to "deny access". For example lets say you have want a number K > 3 always for the program to continue. The all you have to do is use a do- while loop:

```cpp
do
    {
        cout << "Enter the value for the sequence: ";
        cin >> K;

            if ( K <= 3)
            {
                cout << "Write a bigger number!" << endl;
            }
    } while(K <= 3);
```

Otherwise just use a normal loop with the condition suitable for the task.

Comment: Thanks for the "deny access" tip.

Answer (score 0):

**Suppose your program is to find the Factorial of number and you want it to loop such that it ask for new value from the user**

```
int main()
{   
    int n;
    while (true) {
        int factorial = 1;
        cin >> n;
        if (n==0) {
        cout << 0;
        }
        else {
        for (int i=n;i>0;i--) {
        factorial = factorial*i;
        }
        cout << factorial;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```